How to make a working Email hyperlink in HTML CSS
I'm currently learning HTML CSS and am trying to implement a hyperlink to my work email.
My current line of code doesn't have any problems I think but I don't know how to add a email Hyperlink
This is my line of code and I see no issues even after inspecting it multiple times, and if it looks bad I'm sorry, first post here and I'm new to programming.
<Doctype html>
<head>Work Website</html>
 <hr>
<body>
<p href= "pwrbuster-coding@protonmail.com">Email me.</p>
</body>


<a href="mailto:mymail@somemail.com">Email me</a>

Based on which documentation/website do you assume that you can apply href to p an element?

I think to create a link for your work email, you should use the  tag in HTML

Does this answer your question? Hyperlink to email address

Learn HTML first. The codes in the question are totally incorrect.

There are some issues with your code structure. The structure of your HTML code should be as follows:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>

<p> tag is used for defining paragraphs. It cannot be used along with the href attribute.
In order to create a hyperlink to link to other pages, email addresses etc. you need to use the <a> (anchor) tag along with the href attribute.
You need to use the mailto parameter inside the href attribute to link to email addresses.
This will work:
<a href="mailto:pwrbuster-coding@protonmail.com">Email me.</a>

If you wish, you can also add it inside a paragraph like this:
<p><a href="mailto:pwrbuster-coding@protonmail.com">Email me.</a></p>


This is basic HTML; instead of trying to apply the href attribute to the p tag, you should be using the a tag:
<a href="mailto:foo@bar">Email me at foo@bar</a>


Thank you Jeff, I know this is really basic HTML and I probably seem somewhat stupid in it, but I'm just starting out and any help (especially on stuff like this) is amazing, once again, Thank you

This <p> tag is used for paragraphs. For links, you need to use an anchor with this tag <a>.


<p><a href="email.com">My email</a></p>



